# Hibernate Search java spring, searching only entities that have ids as specified

Tags: java, spring, jpa, lucene, hibernate-search

I have a problem when i want to search in entities that have specific ids. I have fullTextQuery that i execute, it works all fine, bud when i want to say

ONLY SEARCH IN THESE ENTITIES (List of ids provided) :

```
+(title:slovakia~2 leadText:slovakia~2 body:slovakia~2 software:slovakia~2) +verified:true +eid:(113 | 112 | 3)
```

[image]

Then i get 0 results, these entities are indexed and persisted, all should be working fine, yet it doesnt return any results.

Here is The entity property defined :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Field(name = "eid")
@FieldBridge(impl = LongBridge.class)
private long id;
```

I have tried, Without field bridge, with TermVector.YES and also without any additional @Field.. annotation. All results either exception or just no results.

**What is a proper way of searching in specific IDs?**

For instance here is the working query:
[image]

Creation of query looks like this :

```
    return Optional.of(getQueryBuilder()
            .keyword()
            .onField("eid")
            .matching(stringBuilder.toString())
            .createQuery());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you tried to use, `(113 | 112 | 3)`, is not correct in this context. Parameters to the `keyword` query are not interpreted, in particular operators are not supported.

Use a boolean junction that matches any of the provided IDs instead:

```
List<String> eids = ...;

QueryBuilder qb = getQueryBuilder();

BooleanJunction<?> idJunction = qb.bool();

for (String eid : eids) {
    idJunction.should(
            qb.keyword()
                .onField("eid")
                .matching(eid)
                .createQuery()
    );
}

return idJunction.createQuery();
```

Note that, if you want to add other queries, you should not use the same junction. Use another junction that includes `idJunction.createQuery()` as one of its clauses.

Comment: Yes, this was correct answer, hm so real query in the end looks like this with your code : +(title:slovakia~2 leadText:slovakia~2 body:slovakia~2 software:slovakia~2) +verified:true +(eid:113 eid:112 eid:3) that works fine and i get expected result. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From the little experience i have had with hibernate-search, only Ranges seem to work well with intenger and long fields. In your example here, i expect the following query should work just fine:

```
QueryBuilder qb = getQueryBuilder();
BooleanJunction<?> idJunction = qb.bool();
 bool.must(NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange("eid", Long.valueOf(eid), Long.valueOf(eid), true, true).createQuery();
```

In this case, the Boxed `Long.valueOf()` is optional if the values being supplied are Long values already.

Comment: Hm looks like this would be a range from certain number all the way to some number? Bud that is not what my requrements are.

Comment: You are not actually providing a range. You are just using the same `id`. `BooleanJunction<?> idJunction = qb.bool();
 bool.must(NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange("eid", Long.valueOf("1"), Long.valueOf("1"), true, true).createQuery();`

In this case the `id` being `1`

Comment: Oh i get it yhe, maybe that would work bud solution from yrodiere is more elegant :D

Comment: The keyword() query works fine with numeric fields too, as long as you correctly pass a value to match that has the same type as the indexed field. In any case, the question explicitly shows that the field is mapped with the legacy `LongBridge`, which indexes long values as strings.